# Pin folders to the top in the Nautilus File Manager

Tags: gnome, nautilus, 22.04, filemanager

**O.S:** Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Is it possible to **Pin folders** to the top in Nautilus File Manager?

[image]

As you can see, in Nemo File Manager it's very simple, the option to pin the desired folders at the top of the File Manager is integrated into the menu (even the option to quickly change the colors of the desired folders are cleverly integrated):

[image]

**Update:**
**I created a thread on the Gnome Forum:**

[Feature Request - Pin folders to the top in the Nautilus File Manager & Folder Colors](https://discourse.gnome.org/t/feature-request-pin-folders-to-the-top-in-the-nautilus-file-manager-folder-colors/13377)

If you want us to be able to Pin folders to the top (as is possible in Nemo File Manager) and change folder colors much more efficiently, we'll have to make our voice heard, we'll have to make noise. Also, sorting the order of folders in Nautilus should be possible via Drag & Drop (user desired order).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new bookmark for your desired folder. Just click and drag it to the left column, right where you can see the option to create the bookmark. It will be added as a direct access point using the file manager. I do not know if it is possible to pin it to the top, but at least it is useful.

[image: create new marker]

Another possibility is to mark the folder as *Favorites*. That way you will have it available inside your *Favorites* folder, but it won't be displayed as a direct access.

[image: favorites]

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I have several projects and would have too many bookmarks on the sidebar.